# Recovering a "dead" STM32F429VGT6

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, st-link

Recently I lost power on my printer with an BTT SKR 2 board (https://github.com/bigtreetech/SKR-2).  I connected my ST-Link v3 to the SWD pins and confirmed I can identify the IC.  I am connecting to the device with SWD mode, 8KHz frequency, Connect under reset, and hardware reset mode.  I have shorted BOOT0 to VCC and BOOT1 to ground.

When attempting to read/write, STM32CubeProgrammer states "data read failed, verify flash protection".  When checking the RDP option byte, it is set to 0xFF instead of the normal 0xAA, 0xBB, or 0xCC.  When attempting to change the readout protection, it is not successful.  I have attached logs below.

### Initial Connection

```
  11:48:16:281 : ST-LINK SN  : *removed*
  11:48:16:281 : ST-LINK FW  : V3J9M3B5S1
  11:48:16:282 : Board       : STLINK-V3SET
  11:48:16:283 : Voltage     : 3.25V
  11:48:16:288 : SWD freq    : 8000 KHz
  11:48:16:288 : Connect mode: Under Reset
  11:48:16:288 : Reset mode  : Hardware reset
  11:48:16:290 : Device ID   : 0x419
  11:48:16:291 : Revision ID : Rev 5/B
  11:48:16:297 : Reading data...
  11:48:16:298 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  11:48:16:298 : Reading data...
  11:48:16:299 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  11:48:16:299 : Reading data...
  11:48:16:300 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x0000CFFF
  11:48:16:800 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x00000000
  11:48:16:800 : Database: Config 1 is active.
  11:48:16:802 : flash loader C:\Program Files\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer\bin/FlashLoader/0x419.stldr is loaded
  11:48:16:802 : Reading data...
  11:48:16:802 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x00000000
  11:48:17:302 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x00000000
  11:48:17:302 : failed to read the requested memory content
  11:48:17:304 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFBB0000
  11:48:17:304 : fail @0x00000001
  11:48:17:403 : UPLOADING OPTION BYTES DATA ...
  11:48:17:404 :   Bank          : 0x00
  11:48:17:404 :   Address       : 0x40023c14
  11:48:17:404 :   Size          : 8 Bytes
  11:48:17:404 : Reading data...
  11:48:17:404 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000008 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  11:48:17:404 : UPLOADING OPTION BYTES DATA ...
  11:48:17:404 :   Bank          : 0x00
  11:48:17:405 :   Address       : 0x40023c14
  11:48:17:405 :   Size          : 8 Bytes
  11:48:17:405 : Reading data...
  11:48:17:405 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000008 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  11:48:17:413 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFBB0FFF
  11:48:17:414 : fail @0x00000001
  11:48:17:414 : UPLOADING ...
  11:48:17:414 :   Size          : 1024 Bytes
  11:48:17:414 :   Address       : 0x8000000
  11:48:17:414 : Read progress:
  11:48:17:414 : Reading data...
  11:48:17:414 : r ap 0 @0x08000000 0x00000400 bytes Data 0x00000080
  11:48:17:899 : r ap 0 @0x08000000 0x00000400 bytes Data 0x00000011
  11:48:17:899 : Error: Data read failed
  11:48:17:958 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFBB0000
  11:48:17:958 : fail @0x00000001
  11:48:18:901 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFBB2003
  11:48:18:901 : fail @0x00000001
  11:48:19:904 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFBB2003
  11:48:19:904 : fail @0x00000001
```

### Option Byte Attempt

```
  11:40:11 : ST-LINK SN  : *removed*
  11:40:11 : ST-LINK FW  : V3J9M3B5S1
  11:40:11 : Board       : STLINK-V3SET
  11:40:11 : Voltage     : 3.25V
  11:40:11 : SWD freq    : 8000 KHz
  11:40:11 : Connect mode: Under Reset
  11:40:11 : Reset mode  : Hardware reset
  11:40:11 : Device ID   : 0x419
  11:40:11 : Revision ID : Rev 5/B
  11:40:12 : UPLOADING OPTION BYTES DATA ...
  11:40:12 :   Bank          : 0x00
  11:40:12 :   Address       : 0x40023c14
  11:40:12 :   Size          : 8 Bytes
  11:40:12 : UPLOADING ...
  11:40:12 :   Size          : 1024 Bytes
  11:40:12 :   Address       : 0x8000000
  11:40:12 : Read progress:
  11:40:13 : Error: Data read failed
  11:40:19:271 : Option byte command : -ob  RDP=170 
  11:40:19:274 : PROGRAMMING OPTION BYTES AREA ...
  11:40:19:274 : Reading data...
  11:40:19:275 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  11:40:19:275 : Reading data...
  11:40:19:275 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  11:40:19:275 : Reading data...
  11:40:19:275 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x0000CFFF
  11:40:19:775 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x00000000
  11:40:19:775 : Database: Config 1 is active.
  11:40:19:775 :   Bank          : 0x00
  11:40:19:776 :   Address       : 0x40023c14
  11:40:19:776 :   Size          : 8 Bytes
  11:40:19:776 : OB buffer: fdaaffcf0000ff0f
  11:40:19:776 : Buffer program...
  11:40:19:783 : halt ap 0 
  11:40:19:783 : w ap 0 reg 15 PC   (0x20000000)  
  11:40:19:783 : w ap 0 reg 17 MSP  (0x20000500)  
  11:40:19:784 : w ap 0 reg 16 xPSR (0x01000000)  
  11:40:19:784 : w ap 0 @0x20001160 0x00000200 bytes Data 0x00000000
  11:40:19:784 : w ap 0 @0x20000000 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x0000BE00
  11:40:19:790 : w ap 0 @0x20000004 0x00000D38 bytes Data 0xF000B580
  11:40:19:791 : w ap 0 @0x20001160 0x00000008 bytes Data 0xCFFFAAFD
  11:40:19:791 : Loader write option bytes...
  11:40:19:791 : Init flashloader...
  11:40:19:791 : halt ap 0 
  11:40:19:791 : w ap 0 reg 0 R0   0x00000001
  11:40:19:791 : w ap 0 reg 1 R1   0x00000000
  11:40:19:792 : w ap 0 reg 2 R2   0x00000000
  11:40:19:792 : w ap 0 reg 3 R3   0x00000000
  11:40:19:792 : w ap 0 reg 4 R4   0x00000000
  11:40:19:798 : w ap 0 reg 5 R5   0x00000000
  11:40:19:798 : w ap 0 reg 6 R6   0x00000000
  11:40:19:798 : w ap 0 reg 7 R7   0x00000000
  11:40:19:800 : w ap 0 reg 8 R8   0x00000000
  11:40:19:800 : w ap 0 reg 9 R9   0x00000000
  11:40:19:804 : w ap 0 reg 10 R10  0x00000000
  11:40:19:805 : w ap 0 reg 11 R11  0x00000000
  11:40:19:806 : w ap 0 reg 12 R12  0x00000000
  11:40:19:806 : w ap 0 reg 13 SP   0x00000000
  11:40:19:807 : w ap 0 reg 14 LR   0x20000001
  11:40:19:808 : w ap 0 reg 15 PC   0x20000005
  11:40:19:808 : w ap 0 reg 16 xPSR 0x01000000
  11:40:19:809 : w ap 0 reg 17 MSP  0x20001138
  11:40:19:809 : w ap 0 reg 18 PSP  0x00000000
  11:40:19:809 : run ap 0 
  11:40:19:809 : halt ap 0 
  11:40:19:809 : r ap 0 reg 0 R0   0x00000001
  11:40:19:809 : w ap 0 reg 0 R0   0x40023C14
  11:40:19:810 : w ap 0 reg 1 R1   0x00000008
  11:40:19:810 : w ap 0 reg 2 R2   0x20001160
  11:40:19:810 : w ap 0 reg 3 R3   0x00000002
  11:40:19:811 : w ap 0 reg 4 R4   0x00000000
  11:40:19:811 : w ap 0 reg 5 R5   0x00000000
  11:40:19:811 : w ap 0 reg 6 R6   0x00000000
  11:40:19:812 : w ap 0 reg 7 R7   0x00000000
  11:40:19:812 : w ap 0 reg 8 R8   0x00000000
  11:40:19:812 : w ap 0 reg 9 R9   0x00000000
  11:40:19:812 : w ap 0 reg 10 R10  0x00000000
  11:40:19:812 : w ap 0 reg 11 R11  0x00000000
  11:40:19:813 : w ap 0 reg 12 R12  0x00000000
  11:40:19:813 : w ap 0 reg 13 SP   0x00000000
  11:40:19:815 : w ap 0 reg 14 LR   0x20000001
  11:40:19:815 : w ap 0 reg 15 PC   0x200000AB
  11:40:19:819 : w ap 0 reg 16 xPSR 0x01000000
  11:40:19:821 : w ap 0 reg 17 MSP  0x20001138
  11:40:19:822 : w ap 0 reg 18 PSP  0x00000000
  11:40:19:822 : run ap 0 
  11:40:23:139 : UPLOADING OPTION BYTES DATA ...
  11:40:23:139 :   Bank          : 0x00
  11:40:23:139 :   Address       : 0x40023c14
  11:40:23:139 :   Size          : 8 Bytes
  11:40:23:139 : Reading data...
  11:40:23:139 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000008 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  11:40:23:140 : OPTION BYTE PROGRAMMING VERIFICATION:
  11:40:23:140 : Error: Expected value for Option Byte "RDP": 0xAA, found: 0xFF
  11:40:23:156 : Error: Option Byte Programming failed
  11:40:23:173 : Reading data...
  11:40:23:175 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  11:40:23:176 : Reading data...
  11:40:23:177 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  11:40:23:177 : Reading data...
  11:40:23:178 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x0000CFFF
  11:40:23:641 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x00000000
  11:40:23:641 : Database: Config 1 is active.
  11:40:23:641 : Time elapsed during option Bytes configuration: 00:00:04.368
  11:40:23:676 : UPLOADING OPTION BYTES DATA ...
  11:40:23:676 :   Bank          : 0x00
  11:40:23:676 :   Address       : 0x40023c14
  11:40:23:676 :   Size          : 8 Bytes
  11:40:23:677 : Reading data...
  11:40:23:677 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000008 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
```

### Full Chip Erase Attempt

```
  12:11:30:295 : ST-LINK SN  : *removed*
  12:11:30:295 : ST-LINK FW  : V3J9M3B5S1
  12:11:30:296 : Board       : STLINK-V3SET
  12:11:30:296 : Voltage     : 3.25V
  12:11:30:300 : SWD freq    : 8000 KHz
  12:11:30:300 : Connect mode: Under Reset
  12:11:30:300 : Reset mode  : Hardware reset
  12:11:30:304 : Device ID   : 0x419
  12:11:30:305 : Revision ID : Rev 5/B
  12:11:30:311 : Reading data...
  12:11:30:312 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  12:11:30:312 : Reading data...
  12:11:30:313 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  12:11:30:313 : Reading data...
  12:11:30:313 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x0000CFFF
  12:11:30:813 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x00000000
  12:11:30:813 : Database: Config 1 is active.
  12:11:30:817 : flash loader C:\Program Files\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer\bin/FlashLoader/0x419.stldr is loaded
  12:11:30:817 : Reading data...
  12:11:30:818 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x00000000
  12:11:31:317 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF7A22 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x00000000
  12:11:31:317 : failed to read the requested memory content
  12:11:31:318 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE0000
  12:11:31:318 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:31:372 : UPLOADING OPTION BYTES DATA ...
  12:11:31:372 :   Bank          : 0x00
  12:11:31:372 :   Address       : 0x40023c14
  12:11:31:372 :   Size          : 8 Bytes
  12:11:31:373 : Reading data...
  12:11:31:373 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000008 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  12:11:31:373 : UPLOADING OPTION BYTES DATA ...
  12:11:31:373 :   Bank          : 0x00
  12:11:31:373 :   Address       : 0x40023c14
  12:11:31:373 :   Size          : 8 Bytes
  12:11:31:373 : Reading data...
  12:11:31:373 : r ap 0 @0x40023C14 0x00000008 bytes Data 0xCFFFFFFD
  12:11:31:382 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE0FFF
  12:11:31:382 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:31:382 : UPLOADING ...
  12:11:31:382 :   Size          : 1024 Bytes
  12:11:31:382 :   Address       : 0x8000000
  12:11:31:382 : Read progress:
  12:11:31:383 : Reading data...
  12:11:31:383 : r ap 0 @0x08000000 0x00000400 bytes Data 0x00000080
  12:11:31:869 : r ap 0 @0x08000000 0x00000400 bytes Data 0x00000011
  12:11:31:869 : Error: Data read failed
  12:11:31:933 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE0000
  12:11:31:933 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:32:871 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE2003
  12:11:32:871 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:33:874 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE2003
  12:11:33:874 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:34:876 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE2003
  12:11:34:876 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:35:878 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE2003
  12:11:35:878 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:36:394 : MASS ERASE ... 
  12:11:36:396 : halt ap 0 
  12:11:36:396 : r ap 0 reg 15 PC   0xFFFFFFFE
  12:11:36:396 : PC value=fffffffe  : 
  12:11:36:396 : Flash erase...
  12:11:36:406 : halt ap 0 
  12:11:36:406 : w ap 0 reg 15 PC   (0x20000000)  
  12:11:36:406 : w ap 0 reg 17 MSP  (0x20000500)  
  12:11:36:407 : w ap 0 reg 16 xPSR (0x01000000)  
  12:11:36:407 : w ap 0 @0x20001160 0x00000200 bytes Data 0x00000000
  12:11:36:407 : w ap 0 @0x20000000 0x00000004 bytes Data 0x0000BE00
  12:11:36:411 : w ap 0 @0x20000004 0x00000D38 bytes Data 0xF000B580
  12:11:36:411 : Init flashloader...
  12:11:36:412 : halt ap 0 
  12:11:36:412 : w ap 0 reg 0 R0   0x00000001
  12:11:36:412 : w ap 0 reg 1 R1   0x00000000
  12:11:36:413 : w ap 0 reg 2 R2   0x00000000
  12:11:36:416 : w ap 0 reg 3 R3   0x00000000
  12:11:36:416 : w ap 0 reg 4 R4   0x00000000
  12:11:36:416 : w ap 0 reg 5 R5   0x00000000
  12:11:36:417 : w ap 0 reg 6 R6   0x00000000
  12:11:36:417 : w ap 0 reg 7 R7   0x00000000
  12:11:36:418 : w ap 0 reg 8 R8   0x00000000
  12:11:36:419 : w ap 0 reg 9 R9   0x00000000
  12:11:36:419 : w ap 0 reg 10 R10  0x00000000
  12:11:36:420 : w ap 0 reg 11 R11  0x00000000
  12:11:36:420 : w ap 0 reg 12 R12  0x00000000
  12:11:36:421 : w ap 0 reg 13 SP   0x00000000
  12:11:36:421 : w ap 0 reg 14 LR   0x20000001
  12:11:36:421 : w ap 0 reg 15 PC   0x20000005
  12:11:36:421 : w ap 0 reg 16 xPSR 0x01000000
  12:11:36:421 : w ap 0 reg 17 MSP  0x20001138
  12:11:36:421 : w ap 0 reg 18 PSP  0x00000000
  12:11:36:421 : run ap 0 
  12:11:36:422 : halt ap 0 
  12:11:36:422 : r ap 0 reg 0 R0   0x00000001
  12:11:36:422 : Loader mass erase...
  12:11:36:422 : w ap 0 reg 0 R0   0x00000002
  12:11:36:423 : w ap 0 reg 1 R1   0x00000000
  12:11:36:423 : w ap 0 reg 2 R2   0x00000000
  12:11:36:424 : w ap 0 reg 3 R3   0x00000000
  12:11:36:424 : w ap 0 reg 4 R4   0x00000000
  12:11:36:428 : w ap 0 reg 5 R5   0x00000000
  12:11:36:429 : w ap 0 reg 6 R6   0x00000000
  12:11:36:429 : w ap 0 reg 7 R7   0x00000000
  12:11:36:429 : w ap 0 reg 8 R8   0x00000000
  12:11:36:430 : w ap 0 reg 9 R9   0x00000000
  12:11:36:431 : w ap 0 reg 10 R10  0x00000000
  12:11:36:431 : w ap 0 reg 11 R11  0x00000000
  12:11:36:431 : w ap 0 reg 12 R12  0x00000000
  12:11:36:432 : w ap 0 reg 13 SP   0x00000000
  12:11:36:432 : w ap 0 reg 14 LR   0x20000001
  12:11:36:433 : w ap 0 reg 15 PC   0x20000217
  12:11:36:433 : w ap 0 reg 16 xPSR 0x01000000
  12:11:36:434 : w ap 0 reg 17 MSP  0x20001138
  12:11:36:435 : w ap 0 reg 18 PSP  0x00000000
  12:11:36:435 : run ap 0 
  12:11:36:437 : halt ap 0 
  12:11:36:437 : r ap 0 reg 0 R0   0x00000000
  12:11:36:437 : Error: Mass erase operation failed.Please verify flash protection
  12:11:36:454 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE0000
  12:11:36:455 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:37:425 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE2003
  12:11:37:425 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:38:428 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE2003
  12:11:38:428 : fail @0x00000001
  12:11:39:431 : r ap 0 @0x1FFF76DE 0x00000004 bytes Data 0xAFAE2003
  12:11:39:431 : fail @0x00000001
```

I have tried all the variations of BOOT0/BOOT1 configurations, as well as attempting to use STLink Utility.  Is there any other way to recover this MCU before condemning it?

Comment: Try to perform a "mass erase", "chip erase", or something similar - without attempting to read anything or change the option bytes. Once a certain level of protection is set, erasing everything is often the only thing you can do.

Comment: I have edited my post with that log as well.  Trying the full chip erase function results in the same error.

Comment: Have you tried tying the boot pin low, then powering on?

Comment: Yes, I have tried BOOT0 held high/low as well as the same with BOOT1 while BOOT0 is held high.

Comment: Also check SPRMOD using STM32Prog. Looks like I got a returned board and several registers were set, including this one which prevented flashing.